# Qt plugin system command qml

Tags: qt, qml, qmake

I want to implement a feature on an UI made in QT. I want that, when I press a button from the UI, the application should send a system command to the machine. For example, when I click the button, the command `sudo systemctl start application.service` should be executed.
The part of the QML file looks like this:

```
    ...

    UIPage {
        id: root

        PopupInterface {
            id: popupInterface
            actions: [ { text: "OK" }, { text: "Cancel" } ]
            title: "Settings"

            ...

            onActionTriggered: {
                if (actionId === "0" && !currentState) {


                        Process.start("/bin/cat", [ "/proc/uptime" ]);


                } else if (actionId === "0" && currentState) {


                        Process.start("/bin/cat", [ "/proc/uptime" ]);


                }
                ...
            }
        ...
```

And this is the header:

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QVariant>

class Process : public QProcess {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Process(QObject *parent = 0) : QProcess(parent) { }

    Q_INVOKABLE void start(const QString &program, const QVariantList &arguments) {
        QStringList args;

        // convert QVariantList from QML to QStringList for QProcess 

        for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length(); i++)
            args << arguments[i].toString();

        QProcess::start(program, args);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QByteArray readAll() {
        return QProcess::readAll();
    }
};
```

I found there a some c++ code for system commands (http://www.xargs.com/qml/process.html), but I don't know where to put it (the header file), because the UI project structure is complex. I'm trying to add this feature to Neptune UI (https://github.com/qtproject/qt-apps-neptune-ui/tree/5.10), and the qml file can be found in `sysui/display/FunctionsPage.qml` What should I do in order to execute a system command from qml file?

Answer (score 0):

You should register the C++ QObject to make it available in the Qml code.
This can be done with the following call:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Process>("yourapp.tools", 1, 0, "Process", &createInstance);
```

You can start by putting it in your main() function, maybe you know a better place yourself.

The `createInstance` function is declared as follows (you should place it somewhere in the same file probably):

```
QObject *createInstance(QQmlEngine *eng, QJSEngine *js)
{
    Q_UNUSED(eng)
    Q_UNUSED(js)

    return new Process;
}
```

You can also register differently, not singleton etcetera. You can find about that in the following doc: [QQmlEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html). But I think the singleton suites your needs